# Do I need to move bitcoins stored in a paper wallet?

Tags: wallet, address

In mid 2012 I used bitaddress.org offline to generate address/private key pairs. I purchased bitcoins and had coins sent to these addresses. Do I have to move these bitcoins to keep them in the active chain? (I've read about the May 15 deadline to update the client, but never use a client).

Answer (score 3):

Uh. No.. leave them be. Unless you need  to spend them.

Comment: A high quality answer on Bitcoin.SE would remove confusion about an "active" chain and inform @d-a-w that the requirement for the May 15'th update applies to Miners in particular.  (etc)